# change thickness of boarder around QPushbutton when Button is selected with keys

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, key, qpushbutton

I made a Gui and on a normal screen switching with keys between buttons works and the selected button can be easily seen. This gui is designed for an underwater screen which is much smaller than a normal screen. On the underwater screen it becomes very hard to see on which button the "cursor" is.

How is this state of the button called when the button is not yet checked but the cursor is resting on it?

The button is a regular QPushButton.

How can I make the line of this bounding box thicker?

In the image the cursor is on the Exit Button and a small blue line can be seen

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width of the border with Qt StyleSheet:

```
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    QSS = """
    QPushButton:pressed {
      border: 4px solid;
    }
    QPushButton:selected {
      border: 4px solid;
    }
    """

    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)

    button_1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button1")
    button_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button3")
    button_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button3")

    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()

    lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
    lay.addWidget(button_1)
    lay.addWidget(button_2)
    lay.addWidget(button_3)

    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: this would be the case once the button is pressed.
But I am looking for the case where the button is not pressed but the cursor is on the button and the button is "selected".

Comment: @JudithFischer try again

Comment: The boarder is still thicker once the button is pressed, but not before